# One-page Bootstrap website loading at the bottom of the page, when it should load at the top

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am stumped by a problem. I have built a one-page Website using Bootstrap. It uses spyscroll to update the navigation and I have added some jQuery to make it run smoothly. However my the website is loading with the bottom of the page on view. I have tried using my Windows desktop, a Windows tablet and a Kindle Fire and it always loads at the bottom of the Website.

If you go to the following URL you can see for yourself.
http://nootech.co.uk/bootstrap-one-page/

The code for the index.php one-page Web page and the jQuery file is at:
https://gist.github.com/nicholasdixon/9ab9f248bbdb60f4eae0f785787020d6

Comment: Looks pretty good, full page on my iPad Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove `autofocus="autofocus"` from input `name="name"`

Comment: As a tradition, when you've got an answer. Please mark as answer too!